# How can we change redirection of url. Read below for detail :

Tags: url-rewriting

How can we change redirection of url. Means i have a site abc.com.au. When i open it in browser abc.com.au or www.abc.com.au, it opens show different url (abc.com.au / www.abc.com.au). Now i want to do setting as such type it show only abc.com.au in browser either we write www.abc.com.au or abc.com.au. Can anybody have a idea regarding redirection of url, then please share with me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change something in your domains DNS or check it with PHP?

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'www.abc.com.au')
{
    header("Location: http://abc.com.au");
}
else
{
    //site
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, But i don't want to solve this by coding. I want to know "how can we change url redirection setting in IIS". If you know kindly share with me.

Comment: If im correct you can do that in Domain Controller > DNS? Add an A-HOST. Im not great with webservers. Hope this helps.